# Simultaneous irreducibility of minimal polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, extension-field

> Let $F$ be a field. Let $u,v$ be elements in an algebraic extension of $F$ with minimal polynomials $f$ and $g$ respectively. Prove that $g$ is irreducible over $F(u)$ if and only if $f$ is irreducible over $F(v)$.

I have only obtained that $f,g$ are irreducible over $F$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$g$ is irreducible over $F(u)$ if and only if $[F(u,v):F(u)]=\deg g$ and $f$ is irreducible over $F(v)$ if and only if $[F(u,v):F(v)]=\deg f$. If consider $[F(u,v):F]$ you are done.